Python Selenium Firefox detach is working, but keep the "browser is under remote controll" mark
So I'm trying to make browser do things in script and then stays alive allowing user to do their things. For now the skript is working, and browser is not closing after it's end. But "browser is under remote controll" icon still stays there even after script is done. Is there a way to remove it?
Here is example of my code:
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options


options = Options()
options.set_preference('detach', True)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')

selenium 3.141.0, python 3.7
